# How to make the time input in the 24 Hours format?

Tags: html

So I want to make an time input, but it came with the 12 hours format. I want to make it to be 24 in the hours format:

```
<input type="time" name="jam" class="form-control" id="jam" placeholder="08.00">
```

How to make it in the 24 hours time format?

Comment: Please make an effort first. Do some googling.

Comment: Sorry sir, my bad... I'm a newbie

Comment: HI, what have you done to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<input type="time" id="appt" name="appt" min="00:00" max="24:00" required>
```

use the min and max fields